# How can I stop earpods from falling out in the cold?

Tags: headphones

I have a nice set of Apple earpods, but I have a problem with them falling out of my ears. All earbuds have some tendency to fall out, but the Apple ones, while comfortable and nice sounding, are particularly slippery. I can't use the in-ear variety because they give me painful ear infections.

Some earbuds I've used have a stickier rubber layer around the circumference that help them not to fall out. Especially in very cold winter conditions when my ear skin is less supple and sticky the rubber holds on well enough to keep the buds in my ear.

I wonder if there is any kind of mild adhesive I can wrap around or apply to the earpod to make it stickier. I'd really like to have a nice reliable way to use these otherwise wonderful Apple ones through the cold months.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, wear them under a pair of [earmuffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earmuffs). (Wikipedia article)  The pods would need no modification and your ears would stay toasty warm.

There are several brands out there that fit snugly on the ears so they would hold the earbuds in place.  It may even improve sound quality.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who often works nights and so needs earplugs to ensure she gets enough sleep. To get un disturbed sleep she uses lumps of what I'd describe as soft wax. Hers were hospital issued but they are available via chemists. I have used this wax to embed my earpiece into and it works! I'd say give it a try as it's cheap and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I found these things a couple of years ago [Earskinz](http://earskinz.com) which are essentially little rubber covers for Apple ear pods. And while they are a tad tricky to get on a little patience will reward you with an ear pod that is much less likely to fall out of your ear.

No relation to the company, just a happy customer.